# How is it possible to view the most viewed question?

Tags: support, feature-request

My question [What did David say to the engineer in Prometheus?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2730/what-did-david-say-to-the-engineer-in-prometheus) has been viewed by more than 7k+ viewers, and now i'm tempted to know which questions are the **most viewed questions** in Movies and TV.

Is it possible to sort the questions **by views** something like sort by votes?

Comment: There is a [feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74917/sort-by-views-on-main-question-pages-next-to-votes) for it, but has received no attention on the matter.

Comment: Using the method described by @BenBrocka - this question: http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/2273/40 is currently the most viewed at over 7500 views, and your question is in second place with over 7000 views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no built-in search function for it, but you can search for "Views:1000" to view only questions with 1000 views or more and then copy the highest view could you see on that page like "views:30000" until you find the highest viewed question.

Comment: Is this method discoverable at all?  I'm curious what other secret search params there are.

Comment: Of course, right after that, I found [this search page](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=) which outlines a bunch of parameters, including the Views: one.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to sort them, but you can filter a tag by the max number of views.  By playing with the number you're filtering on, you can get to, say, the top 10 on a tag.

By typing in "[ridley-scott] views:75" into the search bar I can see all of the Ridley Scott questions with at least 75 views (this shows the current top 10 most viewed questions).  I can also link others to the results by copying the url: [results](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bridley-scott%5D%20views:75).

Answer (score 2):

Views is not the only parameter here, but the most important one, so this might help you anyway:

[m&tv Greatest Hits](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits)

(Read more on the SE blog about [this page/feature](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchanges-greatest-hits/))

Comment: Didn't even know they had this.